# Bootstrap delete record using modal

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with a lot of records which also has update and delete column. I would like to use modal of bootstrap to confirm the deletion of a record.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#dialog-example").modal('show');
});

$("#btn-save").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $("#dialog-example").modal('hide');
});

});
```

```
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="project-detail.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>">
                        <?php echo $project; ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo $desc; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="update-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>" title="Update record">
                        <i class="icon-edit icon-white">
                        </i>
                    </a></td>
                    <td><a href="delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>" 
                  class="btn-show-modal" data-toggle="modal" title="Delete record"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                    <?php 
                    } 
                    ?>

            </table>

            <div class="modal hide fade" id="dialog-example">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5>Confirm Delete</h5>
                 </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                     <p class="modaltext">Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
                </div>    

                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">No<a>
                  <a href="delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-save">Yes<a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But unfortunately I cannot do the delete :( what am I doing wrong in here? Your help will pretty much be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have declared `e.preventDefault();` on your `click handler` for `delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>` so it will not fire and go to this page when they click `Yes`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes that's a silly mistake, now I'm having another issue with the id/code, when I clicked the delete button I checked the code in my yes button but it's not the code that I intended to delete

Answer (score 1):

Dont use e.preventDefault(); for $("#btn-save").click(function(e) {

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling delete action.

```
$(".save").click(function(){
    response = confirm("Delete?");
    if(response)
        $.ajax(/* do ajax call to delete*/);

    $("#dialog-example").modal('hide');
})
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer? I'm a newbie

Comment: He's using the modal as a confirm dialog to link to the delete page. There's no AJAX necessary here.

Comment: @neknekmouh When you click on `.save` there will be ajax call to delete page if user confirms it (.save has to be not link), and in any case you close modal window. In that case you page will not be redirected. P.S. you can use ajax success callback to dynamically refresh page.

Comment: @Justinas thanks so how will I put my delete-project.php in the ajax?